# Vandermonde-like determinant with first row $1,-a_1,-(a_1)^2 ,\dots$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

the determinant is :
 $$\left|\begin{matrix}
1&-a_1&\cdots&-a^{n-1}_1\\
1&a_2&\cdots&a^{n-1}_2\\
1&a_3&\cdots&a^{n-1}_3\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
1&a_n&\cdots&a_n^{n-1}
\end{matrix}\right|$$

so i tried and got this :

$$\left|\begin{matrix}
1&0&0&\cdots&0\\
1&a_2+a_1&a_2(a_2-a_1)&\cdots&a^{n-2}_2(a_2-a_1)\\
1&a_3+a_1&a_3(a_3-a_1)&\cdots&a^{n-2}_3(a_3-a_1)\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
1&a_n+a_1&a_n(a_n-a_1)&\cdots&a_n^{n-2}(a_n-a_1)
\end{matrix}\right|$$

and i dont know how to deal with the $a_k+a_1$  since i need the common factor of $a_k-a_1$.
i would very much need a hint .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $$\det\begin{pmatrix}
1&-a_1&\cdots&-a^{n-1}_1\\
1&a_2&\cdots&a^{n-1}_2\\
1&a_3&\cdots&a^{n-1}_3\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
1&a_n&\cdots&a_n^{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}=\det\begin{pmatrix}
2-1&-a_1&\cdots&-a^{n-1}_1\\
1&a_2&\cdots&a^{n-1}_2\\
1&a_3&\cdots&a^{n-1}_3\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
1&a_n&\cdots&a_n^{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}=\\=\det\begin{pmatrix}
2&-a_1&\cdots&-a^{n-1}_1\\
0&a_2&\cdots&a^{n-1}_2\\
0&a_3&\cdots&a^{n-1}_3\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&a_n&\cdots&a_n^{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}-\det\begin{pmatrix}
1&a_1&\cdots&a^{n-1}_1\\
1&a_2&\cdots&a^{n-1}_2\\
1&a_3&\cdots&a^{n-1}_3\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
1&a_n&\cdots&a_n^{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}$$